# "(pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault" in docker container

Tags: python, docker, pygame

I got the following error when tring to use pygame in docker container (i want to got the display from container):

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
```

To reproduce:

1. Docker installed
2. docker run -it -e DISPLAY -w /pygame_hello_world buxx/pygame_hello_world /usr/bin/python3.4 hello_world.py

Result (for me) is:

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

Current thread 0x00007f465f894740 (most recent call first):
  File "hello_world.py", line 7 in <module>
```

Docker image is [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/buxx/pygame_hello_world/) and you can view hello_world.py content [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/buxx/pygame_hello_world/master/hello_world.py).

If you run the `docker run -it -w /pygame_hello_world buxx/pygame_hello_world /usr/bin/python3.4 hello_world.py` command (without `-e DISPLAY` option) you can see pygame working display with [caca](http://caca.zoy.org/).

What happens ? How to fix it ?

Comment: you are not alone, I too get `Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

Current thread 0x00007f47c673c740 (most recent call first):
  File "hello_world.py", line 7 in <module>
` after building your image, my docker version 1.9.0-rc2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with:

```
docker run -w /pygame_hello_world -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /dev/snd:/dev/snd --privileged -e DISPLAY buxx/pygame_hello_world python3.4 hello_world.py
```

Must allow the docker user to communicate with your X session with `xhost +local:docker`.

Inspired from [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/chrisdaish/firefox/).

Comment: I'm having this Segmentation fault issue whilst compiling a C extension for PHP. Any ideas?